# Keeping models and migrations in sync

Tags: ruby, datamapper, padrino

My first time with Padrino and DataMapper. If I understood correctly,

- `padrino g model Foo` will make `models/foo.rb` as well as `db/migrate/001_create_foos.rb`.
- In order to create an index, I need to specify it in the model, not in the migration.
- `padrino rake dm:auto:{upgrade|migrate}` will generate the database from models, without paying attention to `db/migrate` folder.

So, it seems that migrations are only kept as "just in case" for upgrading production databases. Is there a way to generate a migration from the model? If not, does everyone else also have a headache trying to keep migrations up-to-date as you change your model? How do people write their migrations?

Answer (score 1):

According Padrino documentation i guess you're right. The [Orm section](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/rake-tasks#orm)
states that the *auto* namespace won't use the generated migrations.

> *Basically, instead of writing migrations you can directly edit your schema.rb and perform a non destructive migration with padrino rake ar:auto:upgrade*

I guess you can track the database with migrations removing the *auto* namespace as:

```
rake dm:migrate                # Migrates the database to the latest version
rake dm:migrate:down[version]  # Migrates down using migrations
rake dm:migrate:up[version]    # Migrates up using migrations
```

And generate migrations as described in the [Migration Generator section](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/generators#migration-generator)

Comment: The problem is, I couldn't find any way to make indices using DM migrations. So (unless I'm missing something), I need automigrate.

Comment: I also couldn't find documentation for that. I guess in that case you should try to add the index statement after the migration is generated. Like changing `column :name, String, :index => true` in the create_table block. The source code for that may help (https://github.com/datamapper/dm-migrations/blob/master/examples/sample_migration.rb)

Comment: I tried `column :name, String, :index => true` in the migration; it did not produce an index in the SQL. (And it is not in the example migration.)